Error: Unsupported Server Component type: undefined at stringify (<anonymous>). Using Next 14
I was developing my project on Next.js 14 which had frontend and backend seperated. I encountered an error named Error: Unsupported Server Component type: Module. The error appears in the page.tsx file.As I understand it, this error is associated with the use of server components, although everywhere there is a directive 'use client'.Here is the code for the page.tsx file and the code for the files that are related to it.(Chat.tsx, MessageField.tsx)

page.tsx
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Chat } from '@/components/screens/chats/chat/Chat'
import { NO_INDEX_PAGE } from '@/constants/seo.constants'

export const metadata: Metadata = {
    ...NO_INDEX_PAGE,
}

export default function ChatPage({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
    return <Chat id={params.id} />
}


Chat.tsx
'use client'
import { $fetch } from "@/$api/api.fetch";
import { MessageField } from "./MessageField";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { IChat } from "@/types/chat.types";
import { Message } from "./Message";
import { ChatHeader } from "./ChatHeader";
import { useAuth } from "@/hooks/useAuth";
import { Loader } from "@/components/ui/loader/Loader";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export function Chat({ id }: { id: string }){
    const {user} = useAuth()
    const {data, isLoading} = useQuery({
        queryKey: ['chat', id],
        queryFn: () =>
            $fetch.get<{ data: IChat }>(
                `/chats/${id}
                ?populate[messages][populate][sender][populate][avatar]=*
                &populate[participants][populate][avatar]=*`,
                true
            ),
        select: data => data.data,
        enabled: !!id,
    })

    const correspondent = data?.participants.find(u => u.email !== user?.email)
    const endOfMessagesRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    const scrollToBottom = () => {
        endOfMessagesRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    };
    useEffect(scrollToBottom, [data]);
    
    return (
    <div className="w-8/12 border-r border-border h-full grid"
    style={{
        gridTemplateRows: isLoading ? '1fr .089fr' : '.6fr 6fr .6fr',
    }}
    >
        {isLoading ? (
                <div className='flex items-center justify-center'>
                    <Loader />
                </div>
            ) : (
                <>
                    <ChatHeader correspondent={correspondent} />
                    <div className='p-layout border-t border-border' style={{ overflowY: 'auto', maxHeight: '570px' }}>
                        {data?.messages.map(message => (
                            <Message key={message.id} message={message} />
                        ))}
                        <div ref={endOfMessagesRef} />
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
            <MessageField />
        </div>
    )
}


MessageField.tsx
'use client'
import { $fetch } from "@/$api/api.fetch"
import Field from "@/components/ui/field/Field"
import { useAuth } from "@/hooks/useAuth"
import { useReactQuerySubscription } from "@/hooks/useReactQuerySubscription"
import { useMutation } from "@tanstack/react-query"
import { ArrowRightToLine, Send } from "lucide-react"
import { useParams } from "next/navigation"
import { useState } from "react"

export function MessageField() {

    const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
    const send = useReactQuerySubscription()
    const {id} = useParams()
    const { user } = useAuth()
    const { mutate } = useMutation({
        mutationKey: ['update chat', id],
        mutationFn: () =>
            $fetch.post(
                '/messages',
                {
                    data: {
                        text: message,
                        sender: Number(user?.id),
                        chat: id,
                    },
                },
                true
            ),
        onSuccess() {
            setMessage('')
            send({
                operation: 'update',
                entity: 'chat',
                id: id.toString(),
            })
        },
    })
    const onSubmit = () => {
        if(!message) return
        mutate()
    }

    return (
    <div className="border-t border-border p-layout flex items-center justify-between">
        <Field 
        placeholder="Напсать сообщение..." 
        Icon={ArrowRightToLine}
        value={message}
        onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)}
        onKeyDown={e => {
            if (e.key === 'Enter') onSubmit()
        }}
        className="w-4/5"
        />
        <button 
            onClick={onSubmit} 
            disabled={!message}
            className="hover:text-[#4E7869] cursor-pointer transition-colors">
            <Send />
        </button>
    </div>
    )
}


I've tried everything possible to fix this problem. All similar errors on stackoverflow.com. I even downgraded the Next version, thinking that there might be something wrong with my version. I am doing this project following the example and in that example no such error appeared)).I really hope that I just imported something wrong or added something unnecessary. So far this error is unsolvable for me((.

problem was with imports))
